# How to join two tables only when match is unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Imagine we have 2 tables

```
SourceTable                        JoiningTable
Id  |  Name  | CallingDate         HeardName |  PhoneNumber  | CallingDate
------------------------           -------------------------------------
1   |  Carol | 01-01-2000          Carol     |   122-221     | 01-01-2000
2   |  John  | 01-01-2000          Alex      |   999-999     | 01-01-2000
3   |  Alex  | 01-01-2000          Alex      |   000-000     | 01-01-2000
```

and we would like to match rows from first table with phone numbers but due some business reason we need to bring only records where match is unique. That means for Alexander we shouldn't join anything

```
ExpectedResult
1   |  Carol     |   122-221
2   |  John      |   null
3   |  Alex      |   null
```

What is proper and 'the best' way to write this query for sqlServer?

I have only one idea, something like:

```
select 
  Id, Name, PhoneNumber
from
  SourceTable
  left join
     (select 
         PhoneNumber, 
         HeardName,
         CallingDate
         count(*) over (partition by HeardName, CallingDate) [count]
      from
         JoiningTable
     ) JT on JT.[count] = 1 
             and JT.HeardName = SourceTable.Name
             and JT.CallingDate = SourceTable.CallingDate
```

I don't like this query, because if somebody will add new columns to `joiningTable`, he should add it three times to the query (to inner query column list, to partition by and to on-clause at join). Also I am not sure that will work fine if `joiningTable` will be huge. For ex. 500 000 for every date for 3years. And what if we have index on `CallingDate` on both tables, what is the proper way to use index in required query?

Comment: What rule used for join Carol to Karol? Where appear Alexander in your simple data?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, sorry, just a typo. fixed

Comment: I would use `select *, count(*) over...` and that is **the only time** I recommend `select *`, in a subquery with a single table reference

Comment: Why did you just delete your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517890/get-all-subset-sof-given-array-with-cost-restiction ?

Comment: @Enigmativity oh, sorry. Just incidentally. Thank you for point on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    PhoneNumber
FROM SourceTable
LEFT JOIN ( -- join table filtered by count
  SELECT HeardName, MIN(PhoneNumber) PhoneNumber
  FROM JoiningTable
  GROUP BY HeardName
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) JoiningTable ON JoiningTable.HeardName = SourceTable.Name;
```

[MSSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=5499a4ffc8982b68279f241b338c9b31&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it too. Could you please point me on someway how I can check and be sure about performance in your or my solution? I just worry about subquery will try to be precalculated over whole table. Does it exists any way to prevent it in sql?