# Get all subset sof given array with 'cost' restiction

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a set of typed elements and price for each type

```
var array = new [] 
    {
        new Elem(0, Types.LowCost),
        new Elem(1, Types.MediumCost),
        new Elem(2, Types.MediumCost),
        new Elem(3, Types.HightCost),
    }
```

And prices: `LowCost` - 3, `MediumCost` - 5, `HightCost` - 9

How would you find all possible unique combinations of elements with restriction "sum of costs for all elements doesn't exceed a restriction"?

For example for `MaxCost` = 13 I expect

```
Elem(0)   //cost 3
Elem(1)   //     5
Elem(2)   //     5
Elem(3)   //     9
Elem(0), Elem(1)  //cost 3+5=8
Elem(0), Elem(2)  //     3+5=8
Elem(0), Elem(3)  //     3+9=12
Elem(1), Elem(2)  //     5+5 = 10
Elem(0), Elem(1), Elem(2) // cost 13
```

Comment: @FranzGleichmann tried to write a recursive algorithm, but unfortunately it quit slow. Just imagine maybe somebody know better solution. If you know what I shall to read or research, please, point me on it

Comment: well, you _are_ trying to get _all_ possible cominations. which most likely is a huge amount. so expect it to be slow. but maybe you could share that code at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and get help in increasing its performance. also, reading up on the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) might give you some clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a dictionary of costs:

```
public Dictionary<Types, int> costs = new Dictionary<Types, int>()
{
    { Types.LowCost, 3 },
    { Types.MediumCost, 5 },
    { Types.HightCost, 9 },
};
```

I can do this:

```
var query =
    from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << array.Length).Skip(1)
    let combination = array.Where((x, i) => ((n >> i) & 1) == 1).ToArray()
    let cost = combination.Select(x => costs[x.Type]).Sum()
    where cost <= 13
    select String.Join(", ", combination.Select(x => x.Id));
```

That gives me:

```
0 
1 
0, 1 
2 
0, 2 
1, 2 
0, 1, 2 
3 
0, 3
```